# How can I have the soft asserts that I put in my test script be reported into the ExtentReports Report, under each failed step?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, assert, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am working with a testing framework that uses Selenium, TestNG, Java and ExtentReports for reporting.

I have a Test script which is divided into several steps and at the end of each step I have hard asserts to validate the existence of elements that I am interacting with.

I would like to use some soft asserts in order for my next steps to be able to continue executing, but I would also like to see in the ExtentReport Report, some failure indication for each step, not just at the step when the script fails.

For example, I would like to see in the report something like: step1 - passed; step2 - failed (and logged exeception for cause of error), step3 - passed etc

Currently, if I add a soft assert for an element that cannot be found at step 2 from the example above, that step is marked as passed, and I'd like it to be marked as failed, but also continue on to step 3, 4 etc.

Does anyone know how I can do that, or provide some documentation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these steps are part of one long test method. Try using the concept of child nodes. You can set their status to fail or error etc, when an assertion fails. The issue is you will need to have a hard assertion within a try-catch block to catch `AssertionError` and then set the status.

```
ExtentTest test = extent.startTest("Hello","Yeah");

extent.loadConfig(ExtentReports.class, "extent-config.xml");

test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Before Step details");

ExtentTest child1 = extent.startTest("Child 1");

try{
    //Assertion to be placed here
    child1.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Pass");
} catch(AssertionError e) {
    child1.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Fail");
}
//Add to soft assertion

ExtentTest child2 = extent.startTest("Child 2");

try{
    //Assertion to be placed here
    child2.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Pass");
} catch(AssertionError e) {
    child2.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Fail");
}
//Add to soft assertion

test.appendChild(child1).appendChild(child2);

test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "After Step details");
```

Get a report as below -
[image]

---

Updated
Add this method to the `ExtentTestManager` class and call the static method from the testng test. Though this class can be written in a simpler fashion using `ThreadLocal` - http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#testng-examples

```
public static synchronized void updateStepResult(String childNodeDesc, Object actual, Object expected) {

    ExtentTest test = extentTestMap.get((int) (long) (Thread.currentThread().getId()));
    ExtentTest cn = test.appendChild(extent.startTest(childNodeDesc));

    try {
        assertEquals(actual, expected);
        cn.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Pass");
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        cn.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about this nodes concept - I was not aware of it and did manage to copy your example in order to test it out, however I was not able to implement the logic on my framework's code, as it appears it's is not that simple. The test of my framework is almost identical to this one here: https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/aventstack/extentreports/common/ExtentTestManager.java ; And I have a ConfigBasePage which contains a BeforeMethod that starts the test and an AfterMethod that sets the status of the test and ends it.